# How can I invoke a setter method in the main method?

Tags: java, bluej

```
/**
 * @param newProfitMarginParam is used to set the gained profit margin.
 */
public void setCalculateProfitMargin(double newProfitMargin){
    this.profitMargin = (this.sellingPrice - this.dealerCost) / this.sellingPrice;
}

/**
 * A method to calculate the profit.
 */
public void calculateProfit(){
    double dollar = this.sellingPrice - this.dealerCost;
}


public void main(String[] printDetails){
    System.out.println("Jalopies Are Us Vehicle Summary:");
    System.out.println("Vehicle: " + this.year + " " + this.make + " " + this.model);
    System.out.println("Stock code: " + this.stockCode);
    System.out.println("Dealer Cost: $" + this.dealerCost);
    System.out.println("Selling Price: $" + this.sellingPrice);
    System.out.println("Profit Margin: " + this.profitMargin + "%");
    System.out.println("Dollare Profit: $");
    calculateProfit();
}
```

e.g. here I want to add those aforesaid method in the main method.

How can I do that?

I add the last statement in the main method and I didn't get any Syntex error, but I'm not sure if it's correct or not.

Also how can I add the first method as well?

Comment: Do you intend to run this class using the `java` command? If so, your `main` method should be `static` and you'll need to create a new instance of your class and call the method on that.

Comment: Your methods doesn’t make much sense, the set method doesn’t use the parameter it takes in any way and the calculate method below calculates a value but doesn’t return anything nor does it update any instance variable.

Comment: First things first: yes the call is correct. But the method doesn't realy do anything usefull. It sets the local variable dollar just to forget about it in the next line. (and also your set method, while formal ok has a useless parameter - don't know/don't think this was intented)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These concepts may help you understand better what is wrong with your code: [Java Modifiers](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_modifiers.asp)